# How to get the focused cell in JTable during multiple selection

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a `JTable` with 10 rows. If I have multiple selections on the `JTable`, how do I get the cell that is currently focused?

I have tried to used `JTable`'s `getEditingColumn()` and `getEditingRow()`, but they always return -1 during multiple selection.

Answer (score 13):

The commands;

```
table.getSelectionModel().getLeadSelectionIndex();
table.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().getLeadSelectionIndex();
```

give the selected row and column respectively.

Comment: It is not focused row. It is *selected row*. They may be different if you select a row and then move focus to another application.